# Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync -- Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With the below code I keep getting the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'

```
MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("c:\\tmp\\uploads");

//Error line
Task<IEnumerable<HttpContent>> bodyparts =  await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
```

I think this is an easy one, but I'm missing it.

Comment: using the await keyword usually returns the value and not the task. If you replace the declaration of bodyparts with a var, does the comiler error disappear?

Comment: It does, however Request.Content.Read.... doesn't highlight, which leads me to believe something is wrong there. The code I am using I pretty much got from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx so it should be legit right? :)

Comment: ReadAsMultipartAsync is an extension method, so ensure you've got the namespace included - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944544(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this and it works great. I found it here

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

public class UploadController : ApiController
{
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: kindly loook at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094165/downloading-zip-file-from-httprequestmessage-controller.