# Downloading zip file from HttpRequestMessage : controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a web api's using ASP.NET MVC's which **download** the **zip file** attached in the **HttpRequestMessage**

as below

```
 var task = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            task.Wait();

            if (this.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {

                using (Stream requestStream = task.Result)
                {
                     // Do not know how to copy the above request to file stream or zip (ionic zip) and generate zip file from it
                 }
            }
```

note:

1)

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create("name.zip"))
                        {
                            requestStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        }
```

creates invalid zip..

2) Zip contains many files inside it.

Waiting for your comments

Update 1:

```
 var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(ScriptPath);

                Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);                

                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {

                    Trace.Write(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                   Trace.Write("Server file path: " + ScriptPath);

                }
```

though does not help me

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: looks obvious, but to confirm - you're saving a file on the server, correct? (I'd probably call this an upload)

Comment: @G.Stoynev file inside zip got downloaded but file stream mentioned name is invalid

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Please treat as pseudo as I didn't compile it. <strike>Also you may want to rework the blocking `.Result` call to take advantage of the Async read.</strike>

```
var requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

HttpContent fileContent = requestStream.Contents.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Headers.ContentType != null);

byte[] fileBytes = await fileContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(outputPath))
{
    fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, (int)fileContent.Headers.ContentLength.Value);
}
```

Comment: can you just reframe your answer since i am getting bugs

Comment: You are not providing good questions. If it's not working for you, provide exception details or expected vs. actual outcome. Also this statement from your comments above is confusing: `file inside zip got downloaded but file stream mentioned name is invalid`