# Get name of uploaded file when streaming upload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My server has an API to upload files and convert them to PDF. Right now, the file gets uploaded, saved to disk and then converted. See the (trimmed down) code below:

```
public class ConversionController : ApiController {
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostData() {
        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        var file = provider.FileData.First();
        var originalName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        var fileStream = new FileStream(file.LocalFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // convert file stream and return the PDF response ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I read the file to disk but then immediately get a stream for it so I can feed it to our conversion function (which takes a stream). This seems like a waste to save the file to disk every time. So instead of `ReadAsMultipartAsync()` which saves to disk, I can use `ReadAsStreamAsync()` which will give me the stream that I can give directly to the conversion function.

The problem that I'm having with `ReadAsMultipartAsync()` is that I can't figure out how to get the original file name without having the `MultipartFileData` instance to work with. I know that the name comes with the request as part of the body, but I can't figure out how to access it. How can I get the name of the uploaded file without writing the uploaded file to disk?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586590/request-content-readasmultipartasync-error . Not a duplicate question, but the code sample in the first answer demonstrates how to get the filenames. Alternatively, have a look at the request in Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or a browser's debugger and see what header contains the filename, and retrieve it from the HttpContext.Current's Request object.

Comment: That's the code I have now, which forces me to write to disk before getting the file name (as far as I can tell). I want to get the name without writing to disk. Also, the file name isn't in the header, it's in the multipart form body. I don't think I have direct access to that.

Comment: I can't run that through a debugger at the moment, but I don't see where it's writing to disk, unless the server is doing it behind the scenes or before your `PostData()` method is executed. (I'm probably just missing something.)

Comment: I have the `root` variable that provides a path to disk, which the `provider` then uses to write the file to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`, for example:

```
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var file = provider.Contents.First();
            var fileContents = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

            /// do other stuff

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        });
```

In this case the content is read as a byte array, but the same applies to streams.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I looked at different providers, but for some reason I hadn't come across the memory provider.